# Converting set of HHMMSS.jpg files to video with ffmpeg give only one frame

Tags: ffmpeg, images

I have a set of camerashots in directory with the names of

```
hhmmss.jpg
```

I would like to convert them to video. Using command

```
ffmpeg -i %06d.jpg day.mp4
```

gives mp4 with only one frame. Why and how to fix?

Comment: Are you runnin ffmpeg from the same folder where the images are?

Comment: Have you try to add `-pattern_type glob`?

Comment: I think the pattern glob thing doesn't work in Windows versions of ffmpeg. @Dims %06d looks for files in the following pattern: 000001.jpg 000002.jpg 000003.jpg but your images hare in hhmmss format...

Comment: @Dims are you on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming you are on Windows and want the output video to show 1 image every second. You could use concat + a filelist:

First create a filelist:

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do echo file '%a'>>list.txt
```

Now use list.txt with concat:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -r 1/1 -f concat -i list.txt -c:v libx264  "out.mp4"
```